# Set background color in table view while using Core Graphics to add vertical lines for grid

Tags: iphone, uitableview, background-color, cgcontext

I'm attempting to create a grid-style table using the UITableView by overwriting vertical lines on top of the standard horizontal lines provided by default in a UITableView. I am adapting my code to the example helpfully provided from this blog: http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=153.

First, the code which draws the vertical lines (same color as horizontal lines) is implemented in a file separate from the Table View Controller, called "MyTableCell.m":

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     // Use the same color and width as the default cell separator for now
     CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
     CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.25);

     for (int i = 0; i &lt; [columns count]; i++) {
      CGFloat f = [((NSNumber*) [columns objectAtIndex:i]) floatValue];
      CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, f, 0);
      CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, f, self.bounds.size.height);
     }

     CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

     [super drawRect:rect];
    }
```

Next, in the Table View Controller tableView method, we call [cell addColumn:50] to draw a vertical line 50 pixels to the left of the left-hand side of the view boundary:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 NSString *MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyIdentifier %i", indexPath.row];

 MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[[MyTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];

  UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 30.0,
                 tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease];
  [cell addColumn:50];
  label.tag = LABEL_TAG;
  label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
  label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
  label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
  label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
  [cell.contentView addSubview:label]; 

  label =  [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0, 0, 30.0,
               tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease];
  [cell addColumn:120];
  label.tag = VALUE_TAG;
  label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
  // add some silly value
  label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row * 4];
  label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
  label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
  [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
 }

 return cell;
}
```

I am attempting to change the background of the entire view from white (the default) to black. I attempt to do this by setting the self.view.backgroundColor to black in the viewDidLoad method of the Table View Controller:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

However, when I do this, the vertical lines disappear...

I think somehow setting the backgroundColor in viewDidLoad changes the CurrentContext by the time we get to the drawRect: method, but I don't know how to adjust for that. I've tried setting the background color via CGContextSetFillColorWithColor() inside drawRect: like this:

```
GContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, tableBackgroundColor());
CGContextFillRect(ctx, self.bounds);
```

where tableBackgroundColor() is black like this:

```
    CGColorRef tableBackgroundColor()
{
 static CGColorRef c = NULL;
 if(c == NULL)
 {
  c = CreateDeviceRGBColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // black
 }
 return c;
}

CGColorRef CreateDeviceRGBColor(CGFloat r, CGFloat g, CGFloat b, CGFloat a)
{
 CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
 CGFloat comps[] = {r, g, b, a};
 CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(rgb, comps);
 CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);
 return color;
}
```

However, as soon as I attempt to change the background color using this method, the vertical lines still get wiped out. What am I missing here?

Any ideas are much appreciated in advance!

Comment: aatlo moto code naa apaay. baggha

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd, but perhaps the default implementation of drawRect: draws the background colour. Try moving `[super drawRect:rect]` to the start.

Comment: No effect moving [super drawRect:rect] to the beginning of the drawRect method

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they're disappearing, or that you can't see a light gray line on top of a black background?

In drawRect: I changed

```
 CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
 CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.25);
```

to

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 10.0);
```

And in viewDidLoad, I used `[UIColor yellowColor];` and the lines appear just fine. (I also included a call to `[super viewDidLoad]`, but removing it didn't make any difference.)

Comment: Right, thanks Robot K. I am able to duplicate that. I notice, that with the yellow background, the color of the vertical lines is changed slightly (it should be the same color as the horizontal table lines). It seems that the vertical lines are somehow being drawn in the background, behind the view background color...